# Error running my .jar file using spring-boot failed creating bean with name 'springSecurityFilterChain'

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, spring-mvc

When I run my spring application using Eclipse everything works; But when a built my .jar file using the command `mvn package  -Dmaven.test.skip=true` and try to run it using `java -jar nameApplication.jar` an error happens:

> Error creating bean with name 'springSecurityFilterChain' defined in class path resource org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configuration/WebSecurityConfiguration.class.

Someone can help me please.

> 2021-11-12 00:22:42.750  WARN 11240 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'springSecurityFilterChain' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configuration/WebSecurityConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.servlet.Filter]: Factory method 'springSecurityFilterChain' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/boot/configurationprocessor/json/JSONException
> 2021-11-12 00:22:42.773  INFO 11240 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
> 2021-11-12 00:22:42.777  INFO 11240 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
> 2021-11-12 00:22:42.814  INFO 11240 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
> 2021-11-12 00:22:42.819  INFO 11240 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
> 2021-11-12 00:22:42.853  INFO 11240 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener :
>
> Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
> 2021-11-12 00:22:42.898 ERROR 11240 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed
>
> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'springSecurityFilterChain' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configuration/WebSecurityConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.servlet.Filter]: Factory method 'springSecurityFilterChain' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/boot/configurationprocessor/json/JSONException
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:658) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar!/:5.3.12]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:486) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar!/:5.3.12]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1352) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar!/:5.3.12]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1195) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar!/:5.3.12]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar!/:5.3.12]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar!/:5.3.12]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar!/:5.3.12]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar!/:5.3.12]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar!/:5.3.12]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar!/:5.3.12]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:322) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar!/:5.3.12]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar!/:5.3.12]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:944) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar!/:5.3.12]
> at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918) ~[spring-context-5.3.12.jar!/:5.3.12]
> at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) ~[spring-context-5.3.12.jar!/:5.3.12]
> at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:145) ~[spring-boot-2.5.6.jar!/:2.5.6]
> at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:754) ~[spring-boot-2.5.6.jar!/:2.5.6]
> at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:434) ~[spring-boot-2.5.6.jar!/:2.5.6]
> at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:338) ~[spring-boot-2.5.6.jar!/:2.5.6]
> at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1343) ~[spring-boot-2.5.6.jar!/:2.5.6]
> at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1332) ~[spring-boot-2.5.6.jar!/:2.5.6]
> at com.ejs.algaworksCurso.AlgafoodApplication.main(AlgafoodApplication.java:17) ~[classes!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
> at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
> at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:49) ~[algafood-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
> at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:108) ~[algafood-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
> at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:58) ~[algafood-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
> at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:88) ~[algafood-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.servlet.Filter]: Factory method 'springSecurityFilterChain' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/boot/configurationprocessor/json/JSONException
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar!/:5.3.12]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:653) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar!/:5.3.12]
> ... 29 common frames omitted
> Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/boot/configurationprocessor/json/JSONException
> at com.ejs.algaworksCurso.core.security.WebSecurity.configure(WebSecurity.java:60) ~[classes!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
> at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.getHttp(WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.java:217) ~[spring-security-config-5.5.3.jar!/:5.5.3]
> at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.init(WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.java:315) ~[spring-security-config-5.5.3.jar!/:5.5.3]
> at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.init(WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.java:93) ~[spring-security-config-5.5.3.jar!/:5.5.3]
> at com.ejs.algaworksCurso.core.security.WebSecurity$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$e6147404.init() ~[classes!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
> at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.init(AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.java:338) ~[spring-security-config-5.5.3.jar!/:5.5.3]
> at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.doBuild(AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.java:300) ~[spring-security-config-5.5.3.jar!/:5.5.3]
> at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractSecurityBuilder.build(AbstractSecurityBuilder.java:38) ~[spring-security-config-5.5.3.jar!/:5.5.3]
> at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration.springSecurityFilterChain(WebSecurityConfiguration.java:127) ~[spring-security-config-5.5.3.jar!/:5.5.3]
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
> at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar!/:5.3.12]
> ... 30 common frames omitted
> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.boot.configurationprocessor.json.JSONException
> at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:471) ~[na:na]
> at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:589) ~[na:na]
> at org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader.loadClass(LaunchedURLClassLoader.java:151) ~[algafood-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
> at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522) ~[na:na]
> ... 44 common frames omitted

```xml
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.6</version>
        <!--<relativePath /> lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>ejs.com</groupId>
    <artifactId>algafood</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>algafood</name>
    <description>api delivery food</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <maven.compiler.release>11</maven.compiler.release>
        <dockerfile-maven-version>1.4.13</dockerfile-maven-version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <!-- <dependency> -->
        <!-- <groupId>mysql</groupId> -->
        <!-- <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId> -->
        <!-- <scope>runtime</scope> -->
        <!-- </dependency> -->


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.2</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.plugin</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-plugin-core</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.springfox/springfox-bean-validators -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-bean-validators</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.2</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.plugin</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-plugin-core</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat/jackson-dataformat-xml -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
            <artifactId>flyway-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-lang3 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.rest-assured/rest-assured -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
            <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- ModelMapper -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.modelmapper</groupId>
            <artifactId>modelmapper</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- squiggly adiciona filtros as requisições -->
        <!-- https://github.com/bohnman/squiggly#installation -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.bohnman</groupId>
            <artifactId>squiggly-filter-jackson</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.18</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-s3</artifactId>
            <version>1.11.671</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-freemarker</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-hateoas</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.security.oauth/spring-security-oauth2 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.jsonwebtoken/jjwt -->
        <!-- <dependency> -->
        <!-- <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId> -->
        <!-- <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId> -->
        <!-- <version>0.9.1</version> -->
        <!-- </dependency> -->


        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.auth0</groupId>
            <artifactId>java-jwt</artifactId>
            <version>3.18.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>


    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>docker</id>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>com.spotify</groupId>
                        <artifactId>dockerfile-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>${dockerfile-maven-version}</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>default</id>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>build</goal>
                                    <goal>push</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                        <configuration>
                            <repository>algafood</repository>
                            <buildArgs>
                                <JAR_FILE>${project.build.finalName}.jar</JAR_FILE>
                            </buildArgs>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>


</project>
```

```
    @Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurity extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    private JWTUtil jwtUtil;

    @Autowired
    private UsuarioRepository usuarioRepository;

    @Autowired
    private UserSecurityRepository userSecurityRepository;

    private static final String[] PUBLIC_MATCHERS = { "/swagger-ui.html", "/" };

    private static final String[] PUBLIC_MATCHERS_POST = { "/login", "/usuarios/**" };

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.cors().and().csrf().disable();
        http.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers(PUBLIC_MATCHERS).permitAll()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, PUBLIC_MATCHERS_POST)
                .permitAll().anyRequest()
                .permitAll();
        http.addFilter(new JWTAuthenticationFilter(super.authenticationManager(), 
                jwtUtil, usuarioRepository)); // corrigir
        http.addFilter(new JWTAuthorizationFilter(super.authenticationManager(),
                jwtUtil, userSecurityRepository));

    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder);
    }

    @Bean
    public CorsConfigurationSource corsConfiguration() {
        CorsConfiguration cors = new CorsConfiguration().applyPermitDefaultValues();
        cors.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList(
                "POST", "GET", "DELETE", 
                "PUT", "OPTIONS", "HEAD", "PATCH"));
        final UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", cors);
        return source;
    }

}
```

I SOLVED MY PROBLEM CHANGING THIS CODE

```
@Override
protected void unsuccessfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
        AuthenticationException failed) throws IOException, ServletException {
    response.setStatus(401);
    response.setContentType("application/json");
    
    response.getWriter().append(json());
    
}
```

I call a method in the appendd which was like that:

```
    private String json() throws JSONException {
    long date = new Date().getTime();

    JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
    json.put("timestamp", date);
    json.put("status", 401);
    json.put("error", "Não autorizado");
    json.put("message", "Senha ou usuário inválido");
    json.put("path", "/login");
    return json.toString();

}
```

I change it to this:

```
private String json() {
    long date = new Date().getTime();
    return "{\"timestamp\": " + date + ", "
        + "\"status\": 401, "
        + "\"error\": \"Não autorizado\", "
        + "\"message\": \"Email ou senha inválidos\", "
        + "\"path\": \"/login\"}";
 }
```

Now when I build a container with a .jar file everything works fine. I don't know why, but the first method I was using made the problem to happen.

Comment: *java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError* - add the jar which contains this class to your classpath

Comment: If you solved it rather than adding the solution to the question you should post a an answer to the question so that you could get upvotes for it and so that the question doesn't look like there are no answers.